# Find uppercase substrings and wrap with acronym tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example replace the string `Yangomo, Congo, DRC` with `Yangomo, Congo, <acronym>DRC</acronym>`. There may potentially be mulitple uppercase substings in each string. I assume some form of regex?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, you'd like to search a string for all words that are composed of only uppercase letters, and put them in `acronym` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, a really simple one might be:

```
var replaced = original.replace(/\b([A-Z]+)\b/g, '<acronym>$1</acronym>');
```

Doing this sort of thing always has complications, however; it depends on the source material. (The "\b" thing matches word boundaries, and is an invaluable trick for all sorts of occasions.)

*edit* — insightful user Buh Buh points out that it might be nice to only affect strings with more than two characters, which would look like `/\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/`.

Comment: +1  Except, I would require at least two letters, just to avoid selecting words like A and I. `/\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/g`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use PHP to explode the string, use a regex to find all uppercase letters `/[A-Z]+/` and then use PHP to insert the tags (using str_replace).